# Importing a large .csv file into Google Sheets using Apps Script by breaking the CSV into smaller files

Tags: csv, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've been using Google Apps Script to import CSV's into specific Google Sheets files for a while now and recently ran into the 'Exception: File Sofas & Stuff.csv exceeds the maximum file size.'

Here is the script I have been using and note that it is attached directly to the Google Sheet. I use doPost because I like to call it externally as part of an automation:

```
function doPost(e) {

  var file = DriveApp.getFilesByName("EXAMPLE.csv").next();
  var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(file.getBlob().getDataAsString());
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Feed");
  var lr = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Feed").getLastRow();
  sheet.getRange('A1:Z'+lr).clearContent();
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);
  UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://webhook.com/')
}
```

I found a half solution on Stackoverflow but I don't have enough credits to comment and ask for a specific change to the code.

This script from user @tanaike (I don't know if tags work) is very helpful in breaking up the CSV into new sheets, however I would like to modify it so that I can send it to a specific Google Sheet. Is that possible? At the moment if I run the script on the same file twice I just end up with duplicated spreadsheets and I would prefer it to update existing ones.

```
function createSplitSpreadsheet(obj) {
  var accessToken = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
  var baseUrl = "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/";

  // Retrieve file size.
  var url1 = baseUrl + obj.fileId + "?fields=size";
  var params1 = {
    method: "get",
    headers: {Authorization: "Bearer " + accessToken},
  };
  var fileSize = Number(JSON.parse(UrlFetchApp.fetch(url1, {headers: {Authorization: "Bearer " + accessToken}}).getContentText()).size);

  // Calculate number of output files.
  if (obj.files == null) {
    obj.number = 1;
    obj.start = 0;
  }
  var start = obj.start;
  var end = start + obj.chunk;
  var useFileSize = fileSize - start;
  f = Math.floor(useFileSize / obj.chunk);
  f = useFileSize % obj.chunk > 0 ? f + 1 : f;
  if (f < obj.files || obj.files == null) {
    obj.files = f;
  }

  // Split large file by chunk size (bytes).
  var url2 = baseUrl + obj.fileId + "?alt=media";
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < obj.files; i++) {
    var params = {
      method: "get",
      headers: {
        Authorization: "Bearer " + accessToken,
        Range: "bytes=" + start + "-" + end,
      },
    };
    var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url2, params).getContentText();
    var e = res.lastIndexOf("\n");
    start += e + 1;
    end = start + obj.chunk;
    Drive.Files.insert(
      {mimeType: MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS, title: obj.fileName + (i + obj.number)},
      Utilities.newBlob(res.substr(0, e), MimeType.CSV)
    );
  }

  // Return next start value if there is a next chunk for the resume.
  if (start < fileSize) {
    return {nextStart: start, nextNumber: i + obj.number};
  } else {
    return null;
  }
}

// Please run this function.
function main() {
    var obj = {
        fileId: "#####", // File ID of the large CSV file.
        chunk: 10485760, // 10MB Please modify this for your situation.
        files: 3, // Please input the number of files you want to convert.
        start: 0,
        fileName: "sample",
        number: 1, // Counter of output files. Please input this as a next number.
    };
    var nextStart = createSplitSpreadsheet(obj);
    Logger.log(nextStart);
}
```

I know how to select a specific Google Sheet using 'openById' and grabbing the sheet by using 'getSheetByName' although I don't know enough coding to add these into the code written by @tanaike to dump the CSV data into an existing Google Sheet file.

**EDIT**

I was thinking of some code like this where the sheet is chosen, cleared of data, and then the chunk from the CSV is added. But I'm not sure where to put it. The sheet name would be specified based on which object number the function is on.

```
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("SHEETID").getSheetByName("SHEETNAME" +  obj.number);
  var lr = SpreadsheetApp.openById("SHEETID").getSheetByName("SHEETNAME" +  obj.number).getLastRow();
  sheet.getRange('A1:Z'+lr).clearContent();
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);
```

Comment: First, I apologize that my script was not useful for your situation. And, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. Can I ask you about the detail of your current issue and your goal?

Comment: Hey @Tanaike, your script is awesome so no need to apologise. All I'm looking for is a slight modification (I hope) so that instead of it creating a new file in Sheets every time, I can specify a File ID and Sheet Name to put the CSV into. I've added an edit to my question to hopefully clarify this.